# Docker Quickstart Terminal: cd: /u: Permission denied

Tags: bash, ssh, virtualization, docker

I've just installed Docker for Windows. 
Quickstart terminal creates the 'default' vm, but then it can't access it with text:

```
bash: cd: /u: Permission denied
Looks like something went wrong... Press any key to continue...
```

Do I have to ssh into the machine and grant permissions manually? There's nothing on topic in the official guide. 
Docker toolbox version: 1.9.1a

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Running Docker Quickstart as administrator helped. 
I also had to delete 'default' vm that was created by previous (non-administrator) launch.